# edk2 fail to create DUET+INTEL CHIPSEC

Tags: intel, uefi

I have tried to create DUET device, via USB stick.

I followed the instructions on edk2/duetpkg/readme, and so,e other instructions here- ""

in the last "stage" when writing

```
CreateBootDisk usb F: FAT16/32 IA32/64"
error occur. failed to read and write DRB and MBR.
```

What does it mean? Gow can I fix it?

I am trying to make the DUET device for running CHIPSEC. if anyone have another way for running CHIPSEC, i would be happy to hear it, as i fail to run it.
I tried to use this(http://www.basicinputoutput.com/2016/05/a-tour-of-intel-chipsec.html?showComment=1468170958286#c7703677049387165975) guide but, i am pretty new to this, and could not make a proper UEFI shell so, i tried to make the DUET device.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to be better structured and add error message from the link to question (links might get obsolated).

Comment: I have edited your text so that it would be easier to read.

Comment: thank you. I am new here and not native  English speaker, so I might have some errors. But, any answer for my question ?